# How to account for experimental errors when computing the derivative of a Gaussian process?

Tags: covariance, gaussian-process, kernel-trick, measurement-error, uncertainty

When applying Gaussian process regression upon training data, the covariance function can be generally given in the form: $\Sigma_{i,j} = k(x_i, x_j) + \sigma(x_i) \delta_{i,j}$, where $k$ is a selected kernel and the variable $\sigma(x_i)$ is an error drawn from the experiment. But when the functional form of the error, i.e. $\sigma$, is unknown and simply observed from a small sample of experiments, how can one compute the gradient of the Gaussian process?

For example, an experiment may give $\sigma(x_i)$ at particular training points. But when taking the derivative of $\Sigma$ with respect to $x$ (to get the derivative of the GP), $\sigma$ will be treated as a constant. Consequently, the error on the derivatives will essentially be unaffected by $\sigma$. But surely this does not properly account for the error in the original training data. Are there suggestions for accounting for $\sigma$ when its precise functional form is unknown when trying to compute the derivative of a GP?